# Spinner tutorial shows a malformed spinner widget

Tags: android

I have implemented the [official Spinner tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html), but when I run it, the spinner widget is malformed, I have attached this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

If instead of filling the spinner from code, I use the android:entries in the XML, the widget shows correctly.

Anyone knows why?

EDIT: [Here](http://pastebin.com/CE6Qum1L) is my code. And [here](http://pastebin.com/tP44Pe1W) is the code for main.xml and strings.xml

EDIT2: Ok, now I remember that my code was not extracted from the tutorial, but from the SDK samples directory, so the tutorial is fine, but not the SDK sample.

Comment: The code part where you define the `ArrayAdapter` would be interesting.

Comment: Please post *your* code.

Comment: Ok, I have uploadad it to pastebin, my question is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pay close attention in tutorials. In that tutorial when they instantiate the `ArrayAdapter` they reference another layout than you do.

You've referenced the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` where they have referenced the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` layout.

The first one is used for displaying items in a drop-down and the second one is used to display the default `Spinner` appearance.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have noticed that my code was not extracted from the tutorial, but from the SDK samples directory. After your suggestion, you also have to call the setDropDownViewResource method to style the dropdown items, so they are not too small.